# dedupe merges fail with insuff access on cross ref entity - part 2

Tags: security

I closed out the first issue too soon.  The person is still having an issue.
Organization Sharing settings for most objects are either Public Read/Write or Controlled by Parent exept for Opportunity is Public Read Only (but we do not use Opportunities at this time.  Calendar is set to Hide Details and Add Events, but not sure how that would relate either.
Scenario - she gets a notice from DupeBlocker that she has a potential duplicate contact (based on her criteria) and when she tries to delete the contact, she gets insufficient access rights on cross reference id.  She has CRUD access through my profile, the person who created the contact is in the same role as her.
I set up a sharing rule on contact for read/write and that did not make a difference.  Any thoughts as to what else I can do?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Is there a portal or community? How about triggers on contact?

Comment: Did you got an answer to this? We have an issue with Lead Merge which maybe related to this?